# Where's the deployment directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, odp.net

I'm attempting to deploy ODP.Net with my application using the Oracle Instaclient.  While reading the instructions on this site ([Deploying ODP.Net with Oracle Instant Client](http://alderprogs.blogspot.com/2009/04/deploying-odpnet-with-oracle-instant.html) I see where it says the following: "In subdirectories of ODP.NET20 locate and copy OraOps11w.dll and Oracle.DataAccess.dll to your deployment directory".  The question I have is, "Where is my deployment directory?"  At this point, I haven't deployed my application, so no deployment directory has been created.  Is this article talking about copying the files to my project directory?  Or do I need to manually create a deployment directory to copy these files to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's arbitrary - put them anywhere. In fact you don't need to copy them at all. You could just add them to your install project from their current location. It just recommends copying them to "your deployment dicrectory" so that you can then delete the whole package from that you extracted, since you've got what you need.